# How do you estimate the step-change in a time series model with a change-in-slope?

Tags: time-series, poisson-regression

I have some count data, and have used poisson regression to estimate the time trend. An intervention is implemented at a certain time, and I have allowed a step-change and a change-in-slope at this time. I am trying to work out how to report the size of the step-change.

Here is some example data (this is R code):

```
d <- structure(list(time = 1:50, intervention = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), count = c(27L, 
10L, 28L, 17L, 26L, 28L, 26L, 22L, 21L, 29L, 25L, 33L, 22L, 29L, 
19L, 35L, 27L, 36L, 31L, 27L, 38L, 48L, 33L, 35L, 44L, 40L, 39L, 
38L, 47L, 39L, 22L, 21L, 26L, 16L, 18L, 22L, 15L, 16L, 15L, 18L, 
18L, 12L, 12L, 9L, 11L, 19L, 12L, 9L, 10L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
```

Here is a model with a step-change but without a change-in-slope:

```
m <- glm(count ~ time + intervention, data = d, family = 'poisson')

# plot

plot(d$time, d$count, ylim = c(0, 60), xlab = 'time', ylab = 'count')
lines(d$time, predict(m, newdata = d, type = 'response'), col = 'blue', lty = 3)
```

[image]

The step-change can be reported as 0.33 (95% CI 0.27-0.41)

```
exp(cbind(coef(m), confint(m)))

#                                 2.5 %     97.5 %
# (Intercept)      23.4428917 20.468470 26.7581900
# time              1.0167337  1.009642  1.0238982
# interventionTRUE  0.3339105  0.269626  0.4134894
```

However, I also want to include a change-of-slope. Here is a model with both a step-change and a change-in-slope:

```
m2 <- glm(count ~ time*intervention, data = d, family = 'poisson')

# plot

lines(d$time, predict(m2, newdata = d, type = 'response'), col = 'red', lty = 3)
```

[image]

Now we have two relevant terms for the step change at the intervention. How do I report the size of the step-change and its confidence interval?

```
exp(cbind(coef(m2), confint(m2)))

#                                       2.5 %     97.5 %
# (Intercept)           19.9406071 17.1744624 23.0535891
# time                   1.0264078  1.0186741  1.0342461
# interventionTRUE       4.8906579  2.2085820 10.7974154
# time:interventionTRUE  0.9300491  0.9104426  0.9498756
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question. As you probably noticed, the coefficient for the step change (interventionTRUE) in your second model is a bit puzzling at first glance. It suggests a jump at the intervention point when there was actually a drop. The reason is that the time:intervention term is 0 from time 1 to time 30, then it jumps to 31, 32, 33.. and so on afterwards. You instead want it to be 0 from time 1 to time 31, counting from 1,2,3... as so on thereafter.

The simplest way to code this is by just adding a new variable to the data frame representing the change in slope (I've called it "d_slope"):

```
d <- structure(list(time = 1:50, 
                    intervention = c(rep(FALSE,times=30),rep(TRUE,times=20)),
                    d_slope = c(rep(0,times=31),1:19),
                    count = c(27L, 10L, 28L, 17L, 26L, 28L, 26L, 22L, 21L, 29L, 25L, 33L, 22L, 29L,19L, 35L, 27L, 36L, 31L, 27L, 38L, 48L, 33L, 35L, 44L, 40L, 39L, 38L, 47L, 39L, 22L, 21L, 26L, 16L, 18L, 22L, 15L, 16L, 15L, 18L, 18L, 12L, 12L, 9L, 11L, 19L, 12L, 9L, 10L, 7L)), 
                    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-50L))
```

Then you can run model 2 like this:

```
m2 <- glm(count ~ time + intervention + d_slope, data = d, family = 'poisson')
```

This gives the following output:

```
exp(cbind(coef(m2), confint(m2)))

#                                 2.5 %     97.5 %
# (Intercept)      19.9406071 17.1744624 23.0535891
# time              1.0264078  1.0186741  1.0342461
# interventionTRUE  0.5164747  0.4099095  0.6473551
# d_slope           0.9300491  0.9104426  0.9498756
```

I'd interpret this as follows. There was a step change at the intervention point, with the rate dropping by 48% (95%CI, 35%-59%). There was also a change in the slope. The rate was increasing by around 2.6% per week before the intervention, but declined by 4.6% per week after it (calculated as 1.026 times 0.93 minus 1). The rate ratio for the change in slope is 0.93 (95%CI, 0.91-0.95).

I hope that's helpful, but let me know if anything is unclear.

Note: I've assumed the unit of time was one week. If it isn't, replace "week" with whatever the correct unit in what I've written above.